How would one say "fly too close to the sun"?
The phrase "to fly too close to the sun" comes from the myth of Icarus and his father Daedalus, who almost managed to escape the labyrinth of Crete on hand-crafted wings, until Icarus flew too close to the sun and melted the wax holding his feathers together. This is a myth that, presumably, would be very familiar to an educated Roman.
But how would they express this phrase? My first thought is something like nimis propinque soli volare, and indeed, Horace has the phrase sub curru nimium propinqui solis "beneath the chariot of the sun, which is too close [to the earth]" in Ode I.22, but I'm not sure if there's a more idiomatic way to phrase this—perhaps using a different verb like appropinquo "approach" instead of an adverb, for example.

I think a verb with the ad- prefix together with ad solem would fit nicely, like your example appropinquare, or, more specifically, advolare. H.C. Nutting, in Ad Alpes (chapter XXI, p. 120), writes:

Icarus autem ad solem propius accessit; cuius ardore, cera mollita, alae solutae sunt, ac puer infelix in mare praecipitatus est.

The author is a very reliable stylist. In this case he may have been thinking of Terentius, Andria 1, 1, 130: interea haec soror quam dixi ad flammam accessit inprudentius, sati' cum periclo.
